# long to int conversion in java not working

Tags: java, type-conversion, long-integer

I am working on a problem with big number's in java.

```
int temp =0;
long last = 218212982912L;
temp = (int) last%10;
last = last/10;
```

for the above line of code I get the

```
temp = -4
```

in the first iteration. I am not sure what is the problem. I have tried a lot of solution online available.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon on line 2. I don't know if this was copy/paste from your project, and I'm not sure if that could cause your problem, but just saying.

Comment: Your code does not compile. You need to add "L" to the number.

Comment: Thank you. It is just part of a code i just typed it here for questio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put parentheses around `last%10`

The cast to int is being applied before the modulus operation

Comment: @denis happy to help

Answer (score 1):

The last positive you can get is `2,147,483,647` and when you are explicitly converting a larger number to int, your will get unpleasant results but if you put extra parentheses like `(int) (someLong % 10)`, first the long operation get executed (which results in smaller long value that fits int memory space) and then you can cast it to int without worry